# Unicode characters in string Python

Tags: python, unicode

I have Pandas Series with list of games names, for example:

- \u3010\u6226\u8266\u3011Warship Saga \u30a6
- \u22c6Spider Solitaire+
- \u25bbCHESS

I want to remove all Unicode characters that are "unprintable" (so desirable outcome supposed to look like this - Warship Saga, Spider Solitare+, CHESS)

I tried to do his
 data['Name'] = data['Name'].str.encode('ascii').str.decode('ascii')
but it didn't help
Also just decoding didn't help.
data['Name'] = data['Name'].str.decode('ascii')
Thank you in advance!

Comment: is it all in the same string?

Comment: no, its a pandas series

Comment: those characters are printable.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The string `"\u3010\u6226\u8266\u3011Warship Saga \u30a6"` seems to print just fine.

Comment: I'm trying to group those games, that I have in a dataset by age rating(data.groupby('Age Rating').max()), and on the output I see those names with those symbols. I want to get rid of those symbols even if they are pritable, maybe i formulated the problem incorrectly

Comment: @FilipArtemenkov do get any error trying to encode and decode these names? Have you tried adding the `ignore` flag, as I did in my answer?

Answer (score -1):

This works for me, in python 3, by adding `'ignore'` as a parameter

```
string = '\u3010\u6226\u8266\u3011Warship Saga \u30a6'
string = string.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
print(string)
```

Out:

```
Warship Saga
```

For the whole column:

```
data['Name'] = data['Name'].str.encode('ascii', 'ignore').str.decode('ascii')
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried this, let me know if it helps ;)

```
s= "\u3010\u6226\u8266\u3011Warship Saga \u30a6"
my_string = [chr(i) for i in ([(ord(c)) for c in s])]
for i in my_string:
    if type(i) == str:
        try:
            print(i.encode('utf-8').decode('ascii'))
        except:
            pass
```